# A pointer member variable having different values

Tags: c++, qt

Ok, to begin with, this is my code:

```
HyperSprite::HyperSprite()
{
    _view = 0;
}

void HyperSprite::publish(QGraphicsView* view) {
    _view = view;
}

void HyperSprite::getKFrame() {
    if(_view != 0) {
        qDebug()<<(void*)_view;
    }
}
```

Now, if I call `HyperSprite::getKFrame()` from within `main()`, I get the output:

```
0xbf8ffb84
```

I have a TCP server, which requires this `QGraphicsView*` variable. So whenever a new connection is made, `HyperSprite::getKFrame()` is called. However, whenever I make a connection to my server, this is the output:

```
0x1e425ff
```

I honestly don't understand this. Shouldn't the value of a member remain same throughout? Why is the pointer value changing? As is obvious, whenever I try to use the _view pointer to access any of its members, a Segmentation Fault occurs. I tried using QSharedPointer, but it also results in the same problem. The data of the QSharedPointer automatically changes. Why is this happening?

Comment: You lost me at "whenever I make a connection to my server". What did you do to get the different result, exactly?

Comment: does your debugger have a "data breakpoint", which stops execution when certain piece of memory changes? If it does then you should use it to see exactly when and where the pointer is changed.

Comment: Post some more code.  Post a *complete, minimal* example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How do you call `HyperSprite::getKFrame()` from main if it's not a static function?

Answer (score 1):

"Shouldn't the value of a member remain same throughout? " No. If it is not const, and if it is assigned to a new value, it changes.

Excluding counting a memory violation, there could be these solutions:

1. You deal with another HyperSprite object, that consequently may have a different _view member.
2. void publish(QGraphicsView* view) is called more than once, on different QGraphicsView. or another function member that modifies the value of _view...
3. your _view is public, and an external object changes its value
4. an object is defined friend of your object and has modified the value of _view

something in this mood...

Answer (score 0):

If any variable is changing (doesn't matter if it's a member, doesn't matter if it's a pointer) when you didn't assign to it, you have a memory-management error *elsewhere* in your program.

It could be iterating off one end of a buffer, it could be using a pointer left dangling after freeing the object it pointed it, it could be using a pointer that was never initialized.

If you can use a data breakpoint like Dialecticus commented, you will be able to find this particular error fairly easily.  In general, you should use some tool like valgrind to check for memory management errors like this, since the style that caused this problems likely created other errors that you haven't yet noticed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data gets marshalled over Process-bounderies.